# How can I get the url and / or port number of a sails app before it lifts in /config?

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I'm building a Sails app. In it, I'm using `passport-azure-ad`. When setting up passport, I need to tell it where to send the user after they sign in (for example: `http://localhost:1337/login/callback`), which means I need to tell it the url of the current sails app. But sometimes, the app is on `localhost:1337`, sometimes it's on `localhost:81`, sometimes it's on `localhost:3000`, or if I'm using [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/), it's on `10.18.152.135:3000`, and in production, it's on `https://www.<my-domain>.com`.

This passport strategy doesn't allow relative urls either. I need to send it the full absolute callback url.

Comment: Are you calling the passport functionality from with a controller?

Comment: @Glen no. It's set up before the application starts. I use it as a middleware after.

Answer (score 2):

Use environment-based config files to hard-code different domain URLs